# Long-running SSH command hanging - better strategy?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, freeze

I have long-running command being executed over SSH.  Every so often, the command seems to hang and stop getting any output.  The command is still running on the other machine (in fact, if I Ctrl+C out of the SSH command, it still runs, which is fine), my client just hangs.

My command is running an `ant` target, like this:

```
ssh -tt user@machine 'cd /thedir; export DISPLAY=:80; ant clean test'
```

The `ant` command can take up to an hour.

I imagine this is a bad strategy, since any network blips can occur and mess up my connection.  Can anyone suggest an alternate approach?  My goal would be:

1. My client waits for the command to finish
2. I still receive output from the command
3. If network blips occur, I can still check and wait for the comment to finish

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I am running a full bash script... I don't need a one-liner or anything like that.

Comment: it may be helpful to use 'screen', so that when you disconnect, you can simply reconnect to the session, resuming your output. https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

Comment: @FrankThomas - yes -- add that as an answer. Gain some votes

Comment: Interesting, I'm not familiar with `screen`, and that may be exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll do some digging.

Answer (score 2):

You could try running the command in the background (detached from your user session) and sending yourself the result via email. Kinda like so:

> `ssh -tt user@machine 'cd /thedir; nohup ant clean test 2>&1 | mail -s "The cleanup was completed." your-email@exmaple.com'`

I haven't tested this though.

Comment: I'm hoping my client script will wait for the command to be completed.  This would be a good script just so I know when its done, but my goals are slightly different.

Comment: @BigSean: Well, the point is that you could be disconnected due to "network blips". So, if you're not connected, how is your client supposed to wait for anything? I could only imagine going more complex, like logging to a file and watching that log until the command exits and in case you get disconnected, you still have the log. Or am I misunderstanding the goal?

Comment: I would need the script to hopefully try to re-attach or keep checking until the script was complete.  The script is running in my CI environment for every code checkin, so I need to wait for the script to complete so that the next build step can run.  If the script fails, I need the build to fail.  I'll update the question with more of these details.  Thanks

Comment: @BigSean: In that case I would write something far more complex. But ultimately, I would want to achieve a solution that doesn't rely on this SSH connection at all.

Answer (score 2):

My recommendation is to use a combination of [AutoSSH](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) and screen. autossh will automatically reconnect SSH if the session gets disconnected, and screen allows your program to run independently of the ssh session so that you can reconnect to it in process.

that way, when your network hiccupps, autossh will reconnect, and screen will reattach to your scripts shell.

```
localhost>$ autossh -t remotehost 'screen -Rd'
remotehost>$ scriptname
```

that way, when the ssh dies, autossh will reconnect and automatically reattach the screen session.

http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/Shell/Perfect%20Team:%20autossh%20and%20GNU%20Screen.html